# Is there a way to remove the custom browser frame that occurs during Azure Active Directory B2C SignUp Authentication using Xamarin on Android?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

[image]I have followed the documentation in creating the Authentication Flow, and currently i works fine. However we get a custom web-frame, which doesn't make the app look native. So am wondering if there is a way to remove that. Probably using a WebView or changing the navigation bar.

Comment: You can try to add a navigation bar there to see if it will overlap the custom browser frame.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my above question. So it seems there is an option to add an Embedded WebView in Azure which takes in a Boolean.

The article below fixed it for me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-web-browsers#web-browsers-in-msalnet

Comment: Can you please accept it later (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) which will help more people with same problem:).